# What is the setting for the strict tab adherence when running vim with no configuration?

Tags: tab-characters

When I run vim with no configuration (--clean), in a bash file I cannot move the cursor before any indented tabs. I remember being annoyed by this before I regularly used vim, but early on as I grew my own configuration this stopped happening at some point.

What is the setting that makes this happen? I would like to experiment with using it in case I find that I now prefer this strong tab adherence.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "cannot move the cursor before any indented tabs". Could you please edit the question to include what specific motion commands, what's happening, and what you want to happen instead?

Comment: @Rich I mean that on a line with an indented tab, the cursor cannot go any further left than the `^` position. It's something I noticed when I started using vim and I noticed it again on a fresh server with no added configuration when I wrote this question, but at the moment I cannot reproduce this behaviour (on a fresh instance) and I'm confused about that.

Comment: Could you edit that into the question, please? Also, what motions are you trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean move your cursor by using the <kbd>Bcksp</kbd> key.

The setting that control what you can delete with backspace is `backspace` option:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

I you mean move the cursor using the arrows or `h`,  `l` then @romainl is right and it is the `list` option:

```
set nolist
```

Actually it is not that the cursor cannot go behind the character.

With:

- `list` the cursor is positioned at the start of the tab presentation and
- `nolist` the cursor is positioned at the end of the tab representation

Comment: I'm quite sure the 'list' option doesn't involve in the process. This option is to display lines unambiguously (useful when you have spaces and tabs mixed in lines)

Comment: @gildux read `:help 'list'` one more time.

Comment: @romainl strange, I can read at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_70 that "If list is set, edit buffer lines written while in ex command mode shall be written as specified for the print command with the l flag specified. In open or visual mode, each edit buffer line shall be displayed as specified for the ex print command with the l flag specified. In open or visual text input mode, when the cursor does not rest on any character in the line, it shall rest on the '$' marking the end of the line." And that' how I've been using it since ed

Comment: @romainl just ran Vim and `:help 'list'` to read that "List mode: By default show tabs as CTRL-I is displayed, display $ after end of line.  Useful to see the difference between tabs and spaces and for trailing blanks. Further changed by the 'listchars' option." My old friend's still behaving the same: show lines unambiguously, not moving cursor before/after tab stop. Next paragraph: "The cursor is displayed at the start of the space a Tab character occupies, not at the end as usual in Normal mode. To get this cursor position while displaying Tabs with spaces, use: `:set list lcs=tab:\ \ `"

Comment: Not sure where you are going with that wall of copypasta.

Comment: The "wall of copypasta" shows what you think I did not read. It's like you are referencing some other documentation mortal users don't have access to?

Comment: @gildux @romainl is referring to the second paragraph of `:help list`, which comes just after the bit you pasted.

Answer (score 1):

`:set expandtab` makes it possible to jump to the start of the line using `0` in normal mode.

Comment: This is because `expandtab` makes indents into space characters.

Comment: This seems very plausible, but it's not making any difference on my setup (ie setting `noexpandtab`). Nothing so far suggested has worked, so I am thinking that it is a combination of options (or rather lack of) that makes this happen.

Answer (score 0):

`$ vim --clean` is not "Vim with no configuration", it is "Vim with the default configuration". See `:help defaults.vim`.

Where the cursor lands in a tabulation depends on `:help 'list'`. It is disabled by default and not enabled in `defaults.vim`.

Comment: FWIW, that information is *very* easy to find, just by scanning the documentation of each option in your `vimrc`.

Comment: "With no user configuration" would be easy to deduce for a person with a normal temperament. Every program has default settings. And I have been looking for this setting for weeks before asking. I was looking at `formatoptions`. What may seem easy for you may depend on what you already know.

Comment: Don't you mean where the cursor lands depends on `'tabstop'` ?

Comment: @gildux, no, `:help 'tabstop'` has nothing to do with any of this.